# Can Async Http Client library be use to load bitmap from image path in sd card?

Tags: android, image, asynchronous, bitmap

I am making an image loading library in android. For network connection, I am using Async Http Client library by loopj. Now. if a user give a url/uri of local SD Card image to it, then how can i load it to imageview? Does this library supports th local uris? How can I differentiate the internal and external url?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library for loading images since is a very strong library for that cause. You can load image from local path like `Picasso.with(activity).load(sdCardUri)
            .resize(96, 96).centerCrop().into(viewHolder.image);`

Comment: I know it's a good library but i'm trying to make my own library.

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso For image loading in ImageView;

Use below gradle;

```
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

and then use below code for image loading;

```
ImageView iv;

Picasso.with(ActivityName.this).load(image_uri).into(iv);
```

Comment: i have written in my question that i'm making my own then what's the meaning of using picasso?